# Why this message is displayed?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http, jsp

"Do you want to view the webpage content that was delivered securely...."

Is this message displayed only because http resources are used in a https resource?

Comment: Yes like you said, you're fetching contents from non secure location: it can be anything: images, CSS files, script files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your question, it's because of the mixing of both http and https content.

If you are using Firefox you could go and install the [Firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) to look up all resources that are loaded and then use only one source. You'll find all loaded content under tab 'Net' after you do a reload.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Usually this is static content, such as image, CSS, and JS files.

It is best to avoid mixing content sources on HTTPS pages, as it will cause these sorts of warnings, and can lead to some of your content not displaying to the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. It's unsecure to request HTTP resources from a HTTPS page. You need to replace all absolute URLs to resources by scheme relative URLs.

E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/resources/style.css" />
<script src="http://example.com/resources/script.js"></script>
<img src="http://example.com/resources/image.png" />
```

must be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/resources/style.css" />
<script src="//example.com/resources/script.js"></script>
<img src="//example.com/resources/image.png" />
```

#### See also:

- [What are those URL's that are starting with // - that you can see within Google+ html source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656315/what-are-those-urls-that-are-starting-with-that-you-can-see-within-google)